# Node js return array element in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Please consider this as a part of my schema.

```
newSchema({
   'product':{}
   'productPayment':[{}]
});
```

productPayment has 'n' number of elements each with unique Ids. I want to return only that array element which matches my id. I queried like `schema.findOne({'_id':variables._id,'productPayment._id':variables.productPaymentId})` but it returns whole document, but I want that particular element only. How can I possibly get that? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take help from projections, something like this:-

```
 schema
.findOne({'_id':variables._id,'productPayment._id':variables.productPaymentId})
.select({ productPayment: {$elemMatch: {_id: variables.productPaymentId}}})
```

*this is just a sample code please modify according to your needs

Comment: what is the Friends here?

Comment: Updated answer pls check